# Getting results from SQLCLR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

I have the following issue: I must have a DLL accessed from various clients inside the LAN, that resides in a the PC that hosts the SQL Server.

I need to access this DLL from all the clients in order to have it return a legal-tax checksum.

I thought to create a CLR procedure that calls the DLL in the server and returns the checksum.

I followed some internet examples and created a simple HelloWorld app....

I created a DLL in C#

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static int HelloWorld(int h)
{
    return h;
}
```

I created the assembly in SQL Server:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyChecksum
    from 'C:\Users\Panos\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DigitalSignature\Algobox\bin\Debug\checksum.dll'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

I created the procedure

```
CREATE PROC sp_mychecksum (@h int)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME MyAlgobox.Signatures.HelloWorld
```

The bottom line is that when I execute my procedure (`exec sp_mychecksum

12`) I get only a message

> Command(s) completed successfully

and not the 12

Any clues?

Comment: What do you get if you run `declare @rc int; exec @rc = sp_mychecksum 12; select @rc`?

Comment: This site has some great examples of how to implement CLR scalar and table valued functions as well as stored procedures: http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/articles/sql_server_clr_io_utility.aspx They are also very handy to have in your arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've defined things, the return value from the HelloWorld() method is being returned as the return value of the stored procedure.  So, as suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever in the comments of your question, this will get you what you're looking for on the SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @rc int
EXEC @rc = sp_mychecksum 12
SELECT @rc
```

To have your HelloWorld() method return the value as a resultset, you would have to do something like this (**warning, untested**):

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static int HelloWorld(int h) {
    SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("colname", SqlDbType.Int));
    record.SetSqlInt32(0, h);
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(record);
}
```

However, given your use case, I would think you want to map your existing CLR routine to a SQL function, not a stored procedure.  For example, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_mychecksum(@h int) RETURNS int
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER 
AS
EXTERNAL NAME MyAlgobox.Signatures.HelloWorld
```

And then use it like this:

SELECT dbo.f_mychecksum(12)

Comment: Thanx! But now I need to have the string checksum returned by the DLL function, and it says that only Int, BigInt can be returned